# How to change the format of log message in Logstash json layout logs?

Tags: logging, logstash, log4j2

Is there a way to move the `message` field to the top level?

Our logs aggregator doesn't support this format and we don't want to do any exception only for this case.

```
{
   "level":"INFO",
   "loggerName":"org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator",
   "timeMillis":1703150608194,
   "thread":"kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | logstash-opensearch",
   "logEvent":{
      "message":"[Consumer clientId=logstash-3, groupId=logstash-opensearch] Requesting disconnect from last known coordinator kafka:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)"
   }
}
```

**log4j2.properties**

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFileJson
appender.rolling.fileName = /logs/logstash.json
appender.rolling.filePattern = /logs/logstash-%d{yyyyMMddHHmm}.%i.json
appender.rolling.layout.type = JSONLayout
appender.rolling.layout.compact = true
appender.rolling.layout.eventEol = true
appender.rolling.layout.endOfLine = \n


appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.startup.type = OnStartupTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = CronTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.schedule = 0 * * * * ?
appender.rolling.policies.time.evaluateOnStartup = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 10000

rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = RollingFileJson
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFileJson
rootLogger.appenderRef.routing.ref = RollingFileJson

logger.opensearchoutput.name = logstash.outputs.opensearch
logger.opensearchoutput.level = ERROR
```

Or maybe there is a way to use a https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html?

Comment: `JsonLayout` is deprecated in favor of `JsonTemplateLayout`: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html Use that and customize the fields as you see fit.